# Feedjira: VCR not recording cassetes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feed, vcr, feedjira

I have a very simple controller that grabs some data from rss using Feedjira. I want to test this controller by recording the RSS response. Here is the controller code:

```
  def index
    @news = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse URI.encode("http://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=\"#{query}\"&output=rss")
  end
```

and my spec test:

```
it "should assign news feed", :vcr do
  get :index
  assigns(:news).entries.size.should == 6
  assigns(:news).entries[0].title.should == "First item title"
end
```

and code for vcd config:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join("spec", "vcr")
  c.hook_into :fakeweb
  c.ignore_localhost = true
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  c.around(:each, :vcr) do |example|
    name = example.metadata[:full_description].split(/\s+/, 2).join("/").underscore.gsub(/[^\w\/]+/, "_")
    options = example.metadata.slice(:record, :match_requests_on).except(:example_group)
    VCR.use_cassette(name, options) { example.call }
  end
end
```

For some unknown reason, the VCR cassete is not being recorded in this specific test. All other tests that use web calls are working, but with this one with Feedjira it seems that vcr does not detects the network calls. Why?

Comment: Please add the code for your `VCR.configure` block in spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 0):

According to [Feedjira's home page](http://feedjira.com/), it uses curb, not `Net::HTTP` to make HTTP requests:

> An important goal of Feedjira is speed - fetching is fast by using
>   libcurl-multi through the curb gem.

VCR can only use FakeWeb to hook into `Net::HTTP` requests.  To hook into curb requests, you'll need to use `hook_into :webmock` instead.

Comment: Theoretically it should work, but now with webmock I get this error: Unregistered request: POST https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens... because I use carrierwave fog integration in one of my models...

Answer (score 0):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/commit/7aff89c5dc8a905beca78a97c02ef341e0d29c3f) in Feedjira 2.0, Feedjira uses faraday, which means you can follow the testing guide in the [Faraday readme](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#using-faraday-for-testing) or use VCR.

Feedjira uses VCR internally now too.
[Example](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/blob/master/spec/feedjira/feed_spec.rb#L16)

For example you could use vcr in an rspec example like this,

```
it 'fetches and parses the feed' do
  VCR.use_cassette('success') do
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse 'http://feedjira.com/blog/feed.xml'
    expect(feed.last_modified).to eq('Fri, 07 Oct 2016 14:37:00 GMT')
  end
end
```

Comment: This would benefit from some more detail in the answer itself, not in external links.